# how to make vim-nerdtree-tab auto start

Tags: linux, vim, vim-plugin

I am the newer of vim, after installing the spf13, I got a problem.

I have installed the NERDTree and vim-NERDTree-tab, but I don'w know how to let vim-NERDTree-tab starts on every tabs I open in NERDTree, please help me for this question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs#configuration), this happens automatically in GVIM, but has to be enabled in terminal Vim:

> ```
> g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_gui_startup (default: 1)
> Open NERDTree on gvim/macvim startup
>
> g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup (default: 0)
> Open NERDTree on console vim startup
> ```

So, if that's the case (and you've installed the plugins correctly), just put this into your `~/.vimrc` (or the equivalent in *spf-13*):

```
:let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup = 1
```

PS: There's also a `:NERDTreeTabsOpen` command for interactive use.

PPS: Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Comment: But the thing is it' doesn't show up when I press the t button to open a new tab.

Comment: I would try with a plain Vim installation, just the two nerdtree plugins. If the problem still occurs, report this to the author of nerdtree-tab. If it doesn't, it's probably an issue with spf-13.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got the answer:

if you use spf-13 for your vim as the customization.

You should do this:

```
vim .vimrc.local
```

Then add this:

```
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup = 1
autocmd BufWinEnter * :NERDTreeTabsOpen
autocmd BufWinEnter * :NERDTreeMirrorOpen
```

and if you want the cursor focus on the content you want to edit, type this:

```
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w
```